# Airflow webserver homepage continiously loading and showing errors in html pages

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have installed Airflow - 2.0.0.dev0 using https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/INSTALL

and solved all dependency issues.

Now, these following three things working fine without throwing errors
    ```

```
airflow db init
airflow scheduler
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

```
But on airflow webserver homepage, it's showing loading continuously(in *Recent Tasks*, *Last Run* and *DAG Runs* columns)

On browser console, it is showing these errors

>home:46 GET http://localhost:8080/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2782 GET http://localhost:8080/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2767 GET http://localhost:8080/static/appbuilder/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2782 GET http://localhost:8080/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2793 GET http://localhost:8080/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2794 .........
>home:2795 .........
>home:2796 .........
>home:2797 GET http://localhost:8080/static/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
>home:2854 Uncaught TypeError: $input.typeahead is not a function
    at home:2854
```

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing NPM dependencies, run the following command from the root:

```sh
./airflow/www/compile_assets.sh
```

OR

```
if [[ -d airflow/www/static/dist ]]; then
  rm -f airflow/www/static/dist/*
fi

cd airflow/www/
npm install
npm run build
cd ../..
```